# Three.js - Checkerboard Plane

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, plane

I am attempting to create a checkerboard with Three.js for a webpage 3D example. However, my current code assigns three colors, and I need only two colors (black / white). How can I restructure the math to produce the correct checkerboard?

```
// Geometry
var cbgeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 500, 8, 8 );

// Materials
var cbmaterials = []; 

cbmaterials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide }) );
cbmaterials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide }) );
cbmaterials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, side: THREE.DoubleSide }) );

// Assign a material to each face (each face is 2 triangles)
var l = cbgeometry.faces.length / 2;

for( var i = 0; i < l; i ++ ) {
    var j = 2 * i;
    cbgeometry.faces[ j ].materialIndex = i % 3;
    cbgeometry.faces[ j + 1 ].materialIndex = i % 3;
}

// Mesh
cb = new THREE.Mesh( cbgeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( cbmaterials ) );
scene.add( cb );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

In the case that our dev environments are different, I will suggest this code fix:

EDIT-2:

The 'j's in the index selecting portion should be 'i's, I just changed that right now.

Try this:

```
// Geometry
var cbgeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 500, 8, 8 );

// Materials
var cbmaterials = []; 

cbmaterials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, side: THREE.DoubleSide }) );
cbmaterials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide }) );

var l = cbgeometry.faces.length / 2; // <-- Right here. This should still be 8x8 (64)

console.log("This should be 64: " + l);// Just for debugging puporses, make sure this is 64

for( var i = 0; i < l; i ++ ) {
    j = i * 2; // <-- Added this back so we can do every other 'face'
    cbgeometry.faces[ j ].materialIndex = ((i + Math.floor(i/8)) % 2); // The code here is changed, replacing all 'i's with 'j's. KEEP THE 8
    cbgeometry.faces[ j + 1 ].materialIndex = ((i + Math.floor(i/8)) % 2); // Add this line in, the material index should stay the same, we're just doing the other half of the same face
}

// Mesh
cb = new THREE.Mesh( cbgeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( cbmaterials ) );
scene.add( cb );
```

I commented where I did the line changes.

I put the Math.floor(i/8) in the material index to offset every other layer. Otherwise, it would just be vertical lines.

Also, the 3rd material was removed, leaving behind just white and black to work with.

Thanks for this question, it was fun working it out!

Comment: Thanks for this! However, I need to tweak the code for each face having two triangles, since that's how it is in my environment (?). I changed `i/8` to `i/128`, but not sure what the last change would be? [Current Render](http://i.imgur.com/MHA0pLl.png)

Comment: I edited my answer, please review it and check to see if it works! Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Almost there! Half of the board is now black, and half is white: [Render](http://i.imgur.com/DJ46gob.png) Where can I educate myself to better understand the math?

Comment: Sorry, It took me a shower to realize that the ((j + Math.floor(j/8)) % 2) should have 'i's instead of 'j's. When it comes to the math, I was self taught and I don't know of any good resources. If you would like, I will be more than happy to explain in detail why I made every change I did. I would also be happy to teach some tips and tricks so you can have a clearer and deeper understanding on whats going on.

Comment: Success! I changed these two lines: `((j + Math.floor(j/8)) % 2)` ...To this: `((i + Math.floor(i/8)) % 2)`

Comment: If The edited answer looks right to you, would you please select it as the correct answer? I would appreciate that a lot!

Comment: No worries! I would love to know how the code works, as well as tips for the future. Selected your answer as best answer. Not sure how to message on this website, however.

Comment: I'm not quite sure myself, but I have to go to work right now and I won't be online for another 9 hours. I am following this comment thread, so you can contact me through here for now. Good luck, and I will talk to you later.

Comment: Shoot me an email when you have the time! Sarrus25@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

What about a THREE.ShaderMaterial()?

vertex shader can be something along the lines of,

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main(){
vUv = uv;
gl_FragPosition = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

and then your fragment something like this

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main(){
vec2 tileUV = vec2(500.0, 500.0);//say you want to repeat it 500 times in both directions
vec2 repeatedUV = vUv * tileUV ;
repeatedUV -=floor(repeatedUV);
```

now repeatedUV has a bunch of tiles that are all vec2 within 0-1 range and they repeat

```
repeatedUV.x = floor(repeatedUV.x * 2.0);//should give black or white stripe in U direction
repeatedUV.y = floor(repeatedUV.y * 2.0);// same in the other way
```

then this is something like bool algebra

```
float finalMask = repeatedUV.x + repeatedUV.y;//bottom left 0, bottom right 1, top left 1, top right 2
finalMask *= 1.0 - repeatedUV.x*repeatedUV.y; //all zero except top right
gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(finalMask), 1.0);

}
```

expensive way of doing it i guess, but saves you making 5000 triangles. Procedurally generated.